# Normalize string inputs with Binding ASP.Net Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, model-binding, .net-5, asp.net5

I need to normalized the string data (replace some characters with each other like: 'ی' with 'ي' or trim it). To do so, I have created the following model binder like the following:

```cs
public class StringModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        var value = Normalize(valueProviderResult.FirstValue);

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(value);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

This binder works for both `Query` and `Route` binding but fails if I use `FromBody` attribute. It fails because `BindModelAsync` never gets called. I found another question raised for this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433268/string-trim-model-binder-in-asp-net-core-2) and sadly does not have an answer.

I tried to extend the `ComplexObjectModelBinder` but it is a `sealed` class (and also does not provide any constructor). So I tried to extend `ComplexTypeModelBinder` which is annotated as obsoleted.

I have copied the logic from `ComplexTypeModelBinderProvider` from the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b795ac3546eb3e2f47a01a64feb3020794ca33bb/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/ComplexTypeModelBinderProvider.cs#L27-L38) and to my surprise, the `BindModelAsync` of my `StringModelBinder` receives calls now. But still fails because of the `bindingContext.ValueProvider` contains only a provider for route and the result remains null.

My binder provider at this stage:

```cs
public class MyModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (context.Metadata.IsComplexType && !context.Metadata.IsCollectionType)
        {
            var propertyBinders = new Dictionary<ModelMetadata, IModelBinder>();
            for (var i = 0; i < context.Metadata.Properties.Count; i++)
            {
                var property = context.Metadata.Properties[i];
                propertyBinders.Add(property, context.CreateBinder(property));
            }
                
            var loggerFactory = context.Services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
            return new ComplexTypeModelBinder(
                propertyBinders,
                loggerFactory,
                allowValidatingTopLevelNodes: true);
        }

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(string))
        {
            return new StringModelBinder();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I also tried to create a provider from the body and changed my `StringModelBinder` to:

```cs
public class StringModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            var context = new ValueProviderFactoryContext(bindingContext.ActionContext);
            await new FormValueProviderFactory().CreateValueProviderAsync(context);

            valueProviderResult = context.ValueProviders
                .Select(x => x.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName))
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x != ValueProviderResult.None);

            if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None) return;
        }

        var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue.Replace("A", "B");

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(value);
    }
}
```

#### Now the question is, what is the best way to do this normalization in .Net 5?

To whom may concern: This question may seem duplication but I could not find anything related to .Net 5 and if there is a question answering to the `ComplexTypeModelBinder` issue, it won't be suitable for .Net 5 as it is obsoleted.

Comment: A model binder is created to customize how a model is bound - i.e. how a string/binary body is read and converted to .NET objects. Sounds to me you're going very wrong with the idea, and should just create a static class with the utility method and call it where/when needed

Comment: It means that I need to call the utility method in almost every action and on all the string parameters/properties. I think there should be an easier way to do so.

Comment: You have middlewares, action filters, etc etc etc etc. There are many places and ways to do this, a binder is certainly not the way (you're not binding anything, you're changing stuff that was already deserialized)

Comment: Doing this in `Middleware` or `ActionFilter` means adding reflection to the request lifecycle, would it impact performance. I know it would be very tiny but I am still concern about this. Also, thank you for your support.

Comment: I tried the same thing on Asp.NET Core 6, but could not make it work. This answer almost seemed to work, but it failed to bind the `[FromBody]` values for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47645433/134761

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FromBody` is different from the `FromQuery` and other HTTP verbs.

In the complex model binding (FromBody), you can get them in `bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body`.

```
public class StringModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body))
        {
            var body = reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            var mydata = body.Result;

            //...
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(mydata);
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult test1([ModelBinder(binderType: typeof(StringModelBinder))]string model)
    {

        return Ok(model);
    }
```

Then, pass a string into action.

[image]

Get it in `StringModelBinder`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. But this means that I need the create a value provider as well. There should be some way to use the [built-in value provider](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b795ac3546eb3e2f47a01a64feb3020794ca33bb/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/FormValueProvider.cs), am I wrong? On the other hand, if I read the body for the first property, would I be able to do the same for the second one?

Comment: Yes, you are right, asp.net core has buit-in value-provider. You can pass the json body, then format it and get the second one.

Comment: I actually, did not understand how can I pass the JSON body to the built-in value provider and use it in my string provider. Also, the main question was what is the best way to achieve the task rather than make my implementation works at any cost.

Comment: How do you pass the data from client because you use `[FromBody]`?

Comment: @HamidMayeli, you don't need to use value provider, because `[FromBody]` is different from the `[FromQuery]`. In addition, I have edit the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a custom string converter:

```
    public class CustomStringConverter : System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var value = reader.GetString();

        // Do your stuffs with value

        return value;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value);
    }
}
```

and then register it:

```
services.AddControllers()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new CustomStringConverter());
            });
```